# Get the last modification date of a file in Azure Gen1 via databricks using python

Tags: python, azure, databricks

I store files in an Azure Gen1 datalake that I then retrieve via a python coded databricks job. I want to retrieve the **last modification date** of a file. Is there a way to do it ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [os library of python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)

```
import os
file_info = os.stat(path_to_file)
modified_time = file_info.st_mtime
```

The time will be in seconds, if you want to convert it into date format , use datetime library.

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(modified_time))
```

Make sure to pass the file path in python format, you could understand the format using below command.

```
path = '/dbfs/'
print(os.listdir(path))
```